# Move all files and folders from a directory to another directory

Tags: 7

I am unzipping some files and folders from an upload but the zip contains the files and folders one directory too deep. So currently they are located

path-to-folder/anotherdirectory/

When I need them to be located at

path-to-folder/

I have tried using the PHP rename function but get an error stating http 'wrapper does not support renaming in...'

Does anyone know the Drupal way to do this please

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to rename files by specifying their Url. You can't do that. You have to specify the path to the file. It's a PHP issue rather than a Drupal issue. Try this instead:

```
rename($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path-to-folder/anotherdirectory/filename.ext', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path-to-folder/filename.ext');
```